# How to check if all the elements in a 2D vector are zero?

Tags: c++, vector

I found on Stack Overflow that this single statement can be used to find whether all the elements of a vector are zero, or not, but this is only for 1D vector.

```
bool zeros = std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) { return i==0; });
```

How can I modify it so that it can work for a 2D vector?

Is it possible to implement it by just using a single statement?

Answer (score 4):

Like this (assuming you mean a nested vector):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs;

  std::all_of(vs.begin(), vs.end(), [](const std::vector<int>& v) {
    return std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x) { return x == 0; });
  });
}
```

You could also do something like this:

```
bool check0(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vs) {
    for(const auto& v : vs) {
        for(auto x : v) {
            if(x != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can compare the disassembly of both versions here: https://godbolt.org/z/YzdW7x.

Comment: Looking at the godbolt code, it appears that check0 is a lot simpler than check1. Without getting too much into assembly-level coding, what can one conclude (if at all) from the fact that the assembly listing for check0 is much simpler and shorter? Is it also more efficient?

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/jwsMORuM2gaekecP0__cWCGc4LU take this with a big grain of salt

Answer (score 1):

You can [join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) the 2D vector into a single range, and apply [all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of) on that:

```
auto is_zero = [](int i) { return i==0; };  // some predicate

// vs is some 2D range
bool zeros = std::ranges::all_of(vs | std::views::join, is_zero);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/67cv13bcx).